# Make GroupBy query case-sensitive

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have table and it has some data

[image: Table User]

I'm trying to write GroupBy query like this

```
SELECT  [name] FROM [Example].[dbo].[User] Group By [Example].[dbo].[User].[name]
```

But it shows only one record
[image: Group By query]

I need to get all three records because they are separated with a register. How to write case-sensitive GroupBy query?

Comment: It is normally case sensitive :) perhaps you should provide sample data and expected output

Comment: Case sensitivity is part of collations. You can set the collation in the query itself.

Comment: Sounds like you aren't using a case sensitive collation. You'll either need change your database's/column's collation or use `COLLATE`.

Comment: To explain why your question is being downvoted, this is very likely due to the images you've provided. Images of data, and code, aren't helpful to the volunteers you're asking help from. Data, and Code and text, and should be supplied an `text`. Ideally, if you are supplying data, then supply it as DDL and DML statements (with non ambiguous formats like `yyyyMMdd` for dates); that means the it's readily consumable by the users here. You'll very likely get upvotes for such questions, as well as a lot of users being more than happy to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the collation of the column to one that's case sensitive. For example:

```
SELECT [name] COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AS_SC;
       FROM [Example].[dbo].[User]
       GROUP BY [Example].[dbo].[User].[name] COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AS_SC;
```

Case sensitive collations usually have a `CS` in their name.

To choose which collation to use, you can find the collation of the column with:

```
SELECT c.collation_name
       FROM sys.columns c
            INNER JOIN sys.objects o
                       ON o.object_id = c.object_id
                          AND o.type = 'U'
            INNER JOIN sys.schemas s
                       ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id
       WHERE lower(s.name) = 'dbo'
             AND lower(o.name) = 'user'
             AND lower(c.name) = 'name';
```

A good guess is to take that collation and replace the `CI` (for case insensitive) for a `CS` and use it as demonstrated above.

Answer (score 0):

It's a collation thing. CS meaning case sensitive and CI meaning case insensitive.

I will show you an example:

```
USE YourDb;

WITH CS AS 
(
    SELECT 'CaseSensitive' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS AS ColA 
)

SELECT * FROM CS WHERE ColA = 'casesensitive';

WITH CI AS 
(
    SELECT 'CaseSensitive' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS ColA 
)

SELECT * FROM CI WHERE ColA = 'casesensitive'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.User
ALTER COLUMN name VARCHAR(50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS NOT NULL;
```

Then your query code can stay the way it is now.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of solutions here, depending on your goal. If you need the case sensitive version a lot, but don't want to change the database's/column's collation, I recommend the calcualted column:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO
--Alter the whole database
--ALTER DATABASE [Sandbox] COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI; --Commented out as unlikely to be the answer

CREATE TABLE dbo.[User] --I suggest a different name, USER is a reserved word in T-SQL
    (id int,
     [name] varchar(20)); --Name isn't reserved, but is a keyord, so you probably want to use a different name a again

INSERT INTO dbo.[User] ([id],
                        [name])
VALUES(1,'abc'),
      (1,'Abc'),
      (1,'ABC');
GO

--Current example
SELECT [name]
FROM dbo.[User]
GROUP BY [name];

--use COLLATE

SELECT [name] COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI AS [name]
FROM dbo.[User]
GROUP BY [name] COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI;
GO

--Alter the column's collation
--ALTER TABLE dbo.[User] ALTER [name] varchar(20) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI; --Probably not the right solution either.

--Add a Collated calculated column    
ALTER TABLE dbo.[User] ADD name_CS AS [name] COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI PERSISTED;
GO

SELECT [name_CS] AS [name]
FROM dbo.[User]
GROUP BY [name_CS];
GO
--Cleanup
DROP TABLE dbo.[User];
```